# Alert/warning when template is used for same contact twice

Tags: templates

We use templates to send thank you to our donors. We try to add new templates after a while, to tell a new story. Some donors beat our system, and contributes twice before we change our template.

Do you know a clever way to have an alert or warning to inform back end users, that they are going to use a template already used for a certain contact?

Answer (score 1):

The good news is that mass mails track the template id that was used, so in theory, you could build that functionality.

If you're doing these one at a time, you do have access to past mailings in the activities tab, which may have the information you need.

Not the answer you're looking for, but nice to know that in theory it's possible.

Comment: Nice. I am aware of all this. But I was hoping for something to automatically(?) check if the same template_id is used for the same contact_id more than once...